# Different images in listview, CustomBaseAdapter

Tags: android, arraylist, android-listview, baseadapter

Hi i want to set different images to each row of a listview which is attached to a CustomBaseAdapter.
I already have some code but i am getting a forceclose with a NullPointer in line 49 of the adapter.

```
convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.test, null);
```

Can somebody please help to get this solved?

Thank you in advance.

Code main activity:

```
   private static int icons[] = {R.drawable.ic_dialog_time, R.drawable.eur};
    ...
      ArrayList<SearchResults> searchResults = GetSearchResults();
      kp.setAdapter(new MyCustomBaseAdapter(AndroidLogin.this, searchResults, icons));
```

Solution code CustomBaseAdapter:

```
public class MyCustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

public int images[];
private static ArrayList<SearchResults> searchArrayList;

private LayoutInflater mInflater;

public static class ViewHolder {
       ImageView imgViewLogo;
       TextView txtNaam;
       TextView txtWaarde;
      }

 public MyCustomBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SearchResults> results, int[] images) {
 super();
   mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   this.images = images;
   searchArrayList = results;
  }

public int getCount() {
   return searchArrayList.size();
  }

 public Object getItem(int position) {
   return searchArrayList.get(position);
  }

 public long getItemId(int position) {
   return position;
  }

 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   ViewHolder holder;

   if (convertView == null) {
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.test, null);

    holder.imgViewLogo =(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
    holder.txtNaam = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.naam);
    holder.txtWaarde = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.waarde);

   convertView.setTag(holder);
   } 
   else 
   {
   holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
   }

   holder.imgViewLogo.setImageResource(images[position%2]);
   holder.txtNaam.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getNaam());
   holder.txtWaarde.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getWaarde());


  return convertView;
  }

}
```

Edit Logcat:

```
11-19 17:27:06.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1103): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-19 17:27:06.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1103): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
11-19 17:27:06.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1103):     at com.sencide.MyCustomBaseAdapter.getView(MyCustomBaseAdapter.java:63)
11-19 17:27:06.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1103):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1409)
11-19 17:27:06.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1103):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1216)
11-19 17:27:06.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1103):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1127)
11-19 17:27:06.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1103):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
11-19 17:27:06.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1103):     at android.widget.TableRow.getColumnsWidths(TableRow.java:308)
11-19 17:27:06.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1103):     at android.widget.TableLayout.findLargestCells(TableLayout.java:500)
11-19 17:27:06.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1103):     at android.widget.TableLayout.measureVertical(TableLayout.java:465)
11-19 17:27:06.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1103):     at android.widget.TableLayout.onMeasure(TableLayout.java:431)
11-19 17:27:06.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1103):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
11-19 17:27:06.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1103):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
11-19 17:27:06.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1103):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
11-19 17:27:06.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1103):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
11-19 17:27:06.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1103):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure (LinearLayout.java:309)
11-19 17:27:06.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1103):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
11-19 17:27:06.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1103):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
11-19 17:27:06.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1103):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
11-19 17:27:06.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1103):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
11-19 17:27:06.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1103):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
11-19 17:27:06.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1103):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
11-19 17:27:06.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1103):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
11-19 17:27:06.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1103):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:839)
11-19 17:27:06.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1103):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
11-19 17:27:06.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1103):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-19 17:27:06.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1103):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-19 17:27:06.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1103):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-19 17:27:06.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1103):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-19 17:27:06.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1103):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-19 17:27:06.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1103):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-19 17:27:06.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1103):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-19 17:27:06.894: E/AndroidRuntime(1103):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

list.xml:

```
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
    android:icon="@+drawable/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

you are missing this line in constructor. therefore  mInflater is null, when you try to use it.

Adding the above line to your constructor should solve the NPE.

regarding your second NPE mentioned in the comment.. you forgot to use holder. change the following line to the one i gave in your code.

```
holder.imgViewLogo =(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
```

regarding your third NPE ,mentioned in the comment again, since you are populating the list, position can be more than 2, which is not available in array, you should probably replace

```
images[position]
```

with

```
images[position%2]
```

Comment: Hi Yashwanth Kumar
Thx for the tip, but now i get a nullpointer in line 64: holder.imgViewLogo.setImageResource(images[position]);
Proberly because i do not have android:src="@drawable/icon"in my xml file.
It won`t let me add this code line in the xml file.

Comment: Hi i posted the exception from the logcat in my code.
I also added android:icon="@+drawable/icon" to the manifest and the xml file, still the NullPointer, application forces close

Comment: @Yashwanth Kumar
Hmmm ok thx for that but still the nullpointer in line 63 of baseadapter: holder.imgViewLogo.setImageResource(images[position]);
I edited the logcat.

Comment: @Yashwanth Kumar
You`re still there, i am running into a little problem, i wanted to add a 3rd and 4th etc icon to my list but it only shows the first two.
Maybe something minor can you have a look please, code remained the same as above.
Thx very much

Comment: then do position%4 to show 4 different images one after another. make sure your images array have 4 elements in it.